# Elastic search term query not working on a specific field

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search.

So this is how the index looks:

```
{
  "scresults-000001" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "scresults" : { }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "callType" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "code" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "data" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "esdtValues" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "gasLimit" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
             AND MORE OTHER Fields.......
```

If I'm trying to create a search query in Java that looks like this:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "sender" : {
            "value" : "sendervalue",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "data" : {
            "value" : "YWRkTGlxdWlkaXR5UHJveHlAMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA1MDBlYmQzMDRjMmYzNGE2YjNmNmE1N2MxMzNhYjdiOGM2ZjgxZGM0MDE1NTQ4M0A3ZjE1YjEwODdmMjUwNzQ4QDBjMDU0YjcwNDhlMmY5NTE1ZWE3YWU=",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

If I run this query I get 0 hits. If I change the field "data" with other field it works. I don't understand what's different.

How I actually create the query in Java+SpringBoot:

```
QueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("sender", "sendervalue"))
        .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("data",
                "YWRkTGlxdWlkaXR5UHJveHlAMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA1MDBlYmQzMDRjMmYzNGE2YjNmNmE1N2MxMzNhYjdiOGM2ZjgxZGM0MDE1NTQ4M0A3ZjE1YjEwODdmMjUwNzQ4QDBjMDU0YjcwNDhlMmY5NTE1ZWE3YWU="));

Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withFilter(boolQuery)
        .build();
SearchHits<ScResults> articles = elasticsearchTemplate.search(searchQuery, ScResults.class);
```

Comment: Use `data.keyword` instead since you're doing an exact term search

Comment: Can you show a document that actually has that value that you're trying to match?

Comment: @Val it worked with "data.keyword". But why for the data field do I need to use ".keyword" and for originalTxHash I don t need to do that

Comment: understand the concept of [multifields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/multi-fields.html) in ES.  Use terms query for exact matching and match for searching tokens (in analyzed texts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to do an exact match on a string with a `term` query, you need to do it on the `data.keyword` field which is not analyzed. Since the `data` field is a `text` field, hence analyzed by the `standard` analyzer, not only are all letters lowercased but the `=` sign at the end also gets stripped off, so there's no way this can match (unless you use a `match` query on the `data` field but then you'd not do exact matching anymore).

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "YWRkTGlxdWlkaXR5UHJveHlAMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA1MDBlYmQzMDRjMmYzNGE2YjNmNmE1N2MxMzNhYjdiOGM2ZjgxZGM0MDE1NTQ4M0A3ZjE1YjEwODdmMjUwNzQ4QDBjMDU0YjcwNDhlMmY5NTE1ZWE3YWU="
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "ywrktglxdwlkaxr5uhjvehlamdawmdawmdawmdawmdawmda1mdblymqzmdrjmmyznge2yjnmnme1n2mxmznhyjdiogm2zjgxzgm0mde1ntq4m0a3zje1yjewoddmmjuwnzq4qdbjmdu0yjcwndhlmmy5nte1zwe3ywu",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 163,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```